# GROUP BY on condition based on the start of a string in array of strings, without using UDF

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, startswith

Suppose I have a Spark dataframe `df` with columns "a", "b", "c" in which "b" is an array of strings. I would like to return the results similar to:

```sql
SELECT a, array_contain(b, some_value) b, count(*)
FROM df
GROUP BY a, b
```

Of which `some_value` is any string which begins with 'xyz'. How do I code this efficiently?

Comment: You want the count matching `some_value` within the array `b` right ?

Comment: Hi @Vaebhav, I want to group by  column `b` True or False, and count the rows within.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains`, which is a method of DataFrame's Column class.

```py
df.filter(col("name").contains("your string")).show()
```

You can even use `rlike` if looking for a regex pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a condition like this:

```py
F.exists('b', lambda x: x.startswith('xyz'))
```

[`exists`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.exists.html#pyspark.sql.functions.exists), goes through every element in the array and returns `true` if any of them starts with "xyz".

Use this condition directly in `groupBy`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, ['xyz1', 'zzzz']),
     (1, ['zzzz', 'xyz2']),
     (1, ['zzzz', 'yyyy']),
     (2, ['xyz3', 'zzzz'])],
    ['a', 'b'])

some_val_starts_with_xyz = F.exists('b', lambda x: x.startswith('xyz'))
df = df.groupBy('a', some_val_starts_with_xyz.alias('b')).count()

df.show()
# +---+-----+-----+
# |  a|    b|count|
# +---+-----+-----+
# |  1| true|    2|
# |  2| true|    1|
# |  1|false|    1|
# +---+-----+-----+
```